# Microsoft bond service inheritance

Tags: bond

Is it possible to perform inheritance between bond services?

In particular, I have several services with a common endpoint in each. Can I make them inherit from a service containing that common endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as of December 2017 inheritance of services is not currently supported in C++ or C#.

There are some details that need to be decided on (e.g., what is the name of the inherited method "baseservice.method"? "derivedservice.method"? both?, does inheritance model containment or substitution? how are multiple implementations of the same base hosted on the same endpoint dispatched?) before implementation can move forward. If you'd like to move this forward faster, opening an issue on the [GitHub project](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond) to start the design process would help.

Comment: Thanks Christopher!